# thumbnail image of youtube video in YouTubeThumbnailView android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to access the thumbnail image of `YouTube` video in `YouTubeThumbnailView` `android studio`.

The code:

```
public static void thumbnailfunc(Activity context,final String VIDEO_ID, int ThumbnailID)
{
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail =context.findViewById(R.id.ThumbnailID);

    thumbnail.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(
                YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader)
        {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s)
                {
                    //need to release the loader!!!
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(
                        YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                        YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason)
                {
                    //need to release the loader!!!
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(
                YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView,
                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult)
        {
            //handle error here
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
    com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView.initialize(
      java.lang.String,
      com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView$OnInitializedListener)'
    on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log report clearly shows that Android Studio it is unable to find the Thumbnail view **R.id.ThumbnailID** in your layout. Please check!